# Is there a way to change the wallet.dat location without changing the entire data directory?

Tags: wallet, blockchain, bitcoind, bitcoin-core

I know that Bitcoin supports the `-datadir` command line option which specifies that the wallet.dat and blockchain should be stored in a custom location rather than `%appdata%\roaming\bitcoin` but is there a way to specify a wallet location without also changing the blockchain location? I have a highly secured spot I'd like to stash my wallet.dat in (permanently) but I don't want to stash ~2GB of blockchain data alongside it.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but asking about how to change the default storage location has been posted many, many times. The future canonical question is probably *[Bitcoin-Qt setup: Change block-chain file location, settings? documentation?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9259)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A symlink will do it on Linux.

On Windows there's a symbolic link method as well:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#Windows_7_.26_Vista_symbolic_link

A -walletdir= feature has been requested before:

- http://bitcointalk.org/?topic=2730.0
- https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/68

Comment: +1 That's what I do. But sometimes the symlink gets clobbered (fortunately, just the link, not the wallet): https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/660

Comment: That's fantastic, how did I not know Win7 had symlinks?!

Answer (score 0):

The next Bitcoin Core release will have `-walletdir`, which'll basicly allow you to do it without requiring tricks.

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/0530ba0eae147563921b162ed05347234d8b53c0

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/11466