# How do I move wallet.dat file to a different location?

Tags: wallet

I want to move (not backup, move) the file to a different location. That way bitcoin wallet software open that file up.

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand your question. You want to move your bitcoin wallet to a different device like a usb flash drive or a different directory like from C: to D:?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: I want my wallet software to read wallet.dat from different location.

Comment: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3449/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-wallet-dat-location-without-changing-the-entire-dat?rq=1

Comment: Asking about how to change the default storage location has been posted many, many times. The future canonical question is probably *[Bitcoin-Qt setup: Change block-chain file location, settings? documentation?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9259)*. Possible duplicate of *[Bitcoin-Qt setup: Change block-chain file location, settings? documentation?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9259)*.

Answer (score 4):

If you have already downloaded the data then you will have to move the data to the new folder. If you want to store them in D:\BitcoinData then click on "Properties" of Bitcoin.exe shortcut and add -datadir=d:\BitCoinData at the end as an example:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitcoin\bitcoin-qt.exe" -datadir=d:\BitCoinData