# Separate wallets sharing the same blockchain?

Tags: wallet

Since the blockchain is such a large file, I'd like to have more than 1 account on the same computer share it.  Is that possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to change the wallet.dat location without changing the entire data directory?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3449/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-wallet-dat-location-without-changing-the-entire-dat)

Comment: Not a duplicate: sharing it among different users will present more problems than just moving the directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this with Bitcoin-Qt/bitcoind (at this moment) is to swap the `wallet.dat` in your bitcoin data directory *when the client is not running*.

Another method (if you're on a UNIX-ish OS) is to create multiple data directories, then symbolic link (ln -s) the `blocks` and `chainstate` directories (not `database`) inside your datadirs to a common data dir.

```
mkdir ~/.bitcoin-alt  # new wallet directory
cd ~/.bitcoin-alt
ln -s ~/.bitcoin/blocks ~/.bitcoin/chainstate .
# launch new wallet
bitcoin-qt -datadir=$HOME/.bitcoin-alt
```

Then you can leave the wallet.dat alone. When launching you can specify a `-datadir` based on the wallet that you want to use, and it will share the blockchain dirs.

*However* even with this solution cannot run two bitcoind/bitcoin-qt instances at the same time sharing the block chain! This is currently not possible and will result in corruption if you try.

Comment: You can also create hard links on Windows if you're using NTFS.  I used one to put my Bitcoin directory on a separate drive.

Comment: You cannot use hardlinks to span drives. You probably meant junctions (symlinks) which will span local drives via reparse points.

Comment: These days, won't that trigger a lengthy [rescan](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1249/how-exactly-does-rescan-work) every time you switch between wallets?  Does the [automatic rescan](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=6642.msg99812#msg99812) only go through new blocks created since the last one the wallet witnessed?

Comment: It will have to scan the span of blocks between when the wallet was last used and now. There's only a problem in case the block chain is pruned and doesn't have those blocks anymore, in which case it currently has to redownload from the beginning (this is not a protocol limitation, but re-downloading other ranges of blocks is not implemented as of now).