# Advice on running two wallets please

Tags: wallet, backup

Could anyone tell me please if it is possible to run two versions of the Bitcoin qt client independently on the same pc?

The reason I ask is that I wish to make a bitcoin gift to someone on a USB memory stick.

So I run a fresh wallet, send some Bitcoin to it, then move the whole thing onto a USB stick for the other person to use at some point in time.

Does that sound sensible or is there a better way of doing this?

I already have and run my own wallet.

The person concerned doesn't have a pc of their own at the present time. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Related question: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/11977/bitcoin-qt-multiple-wallets-and-transferring-between

Comment: Related question: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10723/separate-wallets-sharing-the-same-blockchain

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to be running two wallets at the same time. Funds can be received while offline. Do the following:

1. Create a backup of your current wallet.
2. While Bitcoin-QT is NOT running, remove your wallet from the Bitcoin-QT folder.
3. Start Bitcoin-QT and create a new wallet.
4. Copy a receiving address from the new wallet to somewhere.
5. Close Bitcoin-QT and move the new wallet to the USB stick.
6. Restore your Wallet backup, and start Bitcoin-QT
7. Send the amount to be gifted to the receiving address you saved before.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.bitaddress.org

Just print out a paper wallet and send your gift to that address. There are much easier wallets for your friend to use than bitcoin-qt. Mycelium is a nice one because it allows someone to spend directly from a private key (printed on the paper wallet).